# curve in R:'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'

Tags: r, plot

I receive error drawing curve:

```
rho<-function(t,k) ifelse(abs(t)<=k,t^2,(2*k*abs(t))-k^2)
plot(farm~land,data=farmland)
curve(rho(k=19000),xlim=c(-10,10),col="blue", add="TRUE")

Error in curve(rho(k = 19000), xlim = c(-10, 10), col = "blue", add = "TRUE") : 
  'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: `curve` does not operate like `lines` and `points`.  Try it with `rho(x)` instead of `rho(k = 19000)`.  But then you'll probably have other issues with `from` and `to`.  Check `?curve`  Sidenote: `add = TRUE` should not have quotes.

Comment: Is this reasonable? `plot(farm~land,data=farmland)
curve(rho(x,k=19000),xlim=c(-10,10),col="blue", add="TRUE")` Because the graph is just like a semi-circle and doesn't sound to follow the data.

Comment: It's a semi-circle because that is what the `rho` function defines. It's only going to 'follow the data' if the function fits the data. I.e. - `plot(rho(t=-10:10,k=19000))` is just a semicircle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
rho <- function(x, k = 19000) ifelse(abs(x) <= k, x^2, (2 * k * abs(x)) - k^2)
plot(farm ~ land, data = farmland)
curve(rho, from = -10, to = 10, col = "blue", add = TRUE)
```

Note that i added some space to your code, it's much easier to read. Also, the `add` parameter
takes a logical value (TRUE or FALSE), not a character vector ("TRUE" will probably evaluate to TRUE, but never count on this).

Another option is to use `lines`:

```
plot(farm ~ land, data = farmland)
x = seq(-10, 10, by = 0.01)
lines(x, rho(x, k = 19000), col = 'blue')
```

Comment: No need to drop `k` from the function. As long as `x` is in there is is a-ok.

Comment: And how do i pass `k` inside `curve`?

Comment: `curve(rho(x,k=19000), from = -10, to = 10, col = "blue")` and away you go -

Comment: Thanks, i edited the answer. But what if there's no default `k`?

Comment: You need to pass all the inputs into the function except `x`. If there's no default you need to specify them, otherwise `curve` can't calculate a value to plot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in-place currying with care, just remember that `curve()` expects a function already defined "outside", or an expression with the symbol `x`. Looks a little like alien code, but here is a (somewhat artificial) example.

```
hist(rexp(10^4), prob = TRUE, breaks = "FD")

g <- function(x, k) ifelse(x <= 1, x^k, x^-k)

curve({\(.) g(., k = 2)}(x), col = "blue", lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
```